# Enable Framebuffer console on android device, "fail to wake up" error

Tags: android, framebuffer

I'm trying to fix the framebuffer console on a sony e1 phone. I have all the required configurations, removed all references to qcom cont-splash-enabled from dts. I slightly modified the drivers/video/mdss/mdss_fb.c so I can better understand what is happening.

```
result = pm_runtime_get_sync(info->dev);
    if (result < 0) {
-       pr_err("pm_runtime: fail to wake up\n");
+       if (result == -EINPROGRESS) {
+           pr_err("pm_runtime: operation already in progress\n");
+       }
+       else if (result == -EINVAL) {
+           pr_err("pm_runtime: Invalid argument\n");
+
+       }
+       else if (result== -EACCES) {
+           pr_err("pm_runtime:  Permission denied\n");
+
+       }
+
+       else {
+           pr_err("pm_runtime: fail to wake up\n");
+           pr_err("pm_runtime: pm_runtime_get_sync returned %d\n",result);
+       };
+       goto pm_error;
}
```

dmesg | grep fb shows:

```
<6>[    0.000000] Node qcom,mdss_fb_primary memblock_reserve memory 3200000-3600000
<5>[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=tty0,115200 fbcon=font:VGA8x8 androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 maxcpus=2 msm_rtb.filter=0x3F ehci-hcd.park=3 msm_rtb.enable=0 lpj=192598 dwc3.maximum_speed"
<6>[    0.626139] pil_pronto fb21b000.qcom,pronto: using secure boot
<6>[    0.694344] mdss_fb_parse_dt: split framebuffer left=0 right=0
<6>[    0.694778] mdp3_alloc: allocating 3072000 bytes at c3200000 (3200000 phys) for fb 0
<3>[    0.695718] mdss_fb_open: pm_runtime:  Permission denied
<6>[    0.696161] mdss_fb_register: FrameBuffer[0] 480x800 registered successfully!
```

pm_runtime_get_sync calls __pm_runtime_resume which calls rpm_resume.
rpm_resume returns -EACCES (only when disable_depth==1).

I have read that by default all devices have disable_depth == 1. I don't know if there is a bug on the mdss side. I haven't worked on Linux drivers, I can't relate to that. It took me a few hours and I don't have the strength to cope with it.

rpm_resume function in https://github.com/msm8610/msm8610_kernel/blob/8x10/drivers/base/power/runtime.c line 488

Source code for the kernel:        https://github.com/msm8610/msm8610_kernel/tree/8x10

PostmarketOS community found that disabling MSM 3D graphics driver and "2D" driver makes framebuffer working[1](https://github.com/postmarketOS/pmbootstrap/pull/66). I will try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to implenet framebuffer functions, based on this commit[1](https://github.com/peterius/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource_fbcon/commit/3a597ba2da05e6fbd31eaabf252484354700c5b8)

That's the efect:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oLaFZ7RXTNfjWdBU54LfeR0sQBKtqb6Z/view?usp=sharing